# Flow mapper not working?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, flow-map

I am trying to run the test files for flow mapper plugin in QGIS but I run into an error message.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, it would help a lot if you could give the specific error message and versions of QGIS and the Plug in you are using, whilst the screen shot is some help, it is difficult to read and not searchable for future readers of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following solutions:

1. Check that you correctly selected mandatory input txt files (node_coordinates and flow_matrix) and be sure that you typed an output file name for the shapefile that will store flow features.
2. It is also advisable that you do not enter long paths and file names as output shapefile. (e.g. locate input and output files to c:\data\ ) Do not include space either in paths or file names (prefer _ under_score).